# How to generalise this further using (variadic) templates

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I am having trouble going the second step or level in templating my code. I have stripped the code to its bare essentials for readability.

I have looked through a lot of templates questions, but I was not really able to solve my exact issue.

I currently have a class RIVRecord, which I templated like this

```
template <class T>
class RIVRecord
{

private:
    std::vector<T> values;
public:

    std::string name;

    RIVRecord(std::string _name, std::vector<T> _values) { name = _name; values = _values;  };
    ~RIVRecord(void) {  };

    size_t size() {
        return values.size();
    }

    T* Value(int index) {
        return &values[index];
    }
}
```

Easy enough. The T types are usually primitive types such as floats and integers. Then I want to put these RIVRecords in a DataSet class. Here is where I am having more difficulty. Untemplated it would be something like this:

```
class RIVDataSet
{
private :
    //How to template this??
    vector<RIVRecord<float>> float_records;
    vector<RIVRecord<int>> int_records;

public:
    RIVDataSet(void);
    ~RIVDataSet(void);
    //And this
    void AddRecord(RIVRecord<float> record) {
        //How would this work?    
    }
    //And this?
    RIVRecord<float> GetFloatRecord();
};
```

I come from a Java background, so there I could use the `vector<?>` and do type checking whenever I ask a RIVRecord. But this does not seem possible in C++. I tried using variadic templates but am unsure how to construct the vector using all types in the template :

```
template <class... Ts>
class RIVDataSet
{
private :        
    //For each T in Ts
    vector<RIVRecord<T>> records;

public:
    RIVDataSet(void);
    ~RIVDataSet(void);
    //For each T in Ts
    void AddRecord(RIVRecord<T> record) {
        //How would this work?    
    }
    //For each T in Ts, get the record by index.
    RIVRecord<T> GetRecord(int index);
};
```

I already saw that this sort of iteration in C++ templates is not possible, but it is just to clarify what I would want.

Any help is very welcome, thank you.

**EDIT:**

There is no restriction on the number of types (floats, ints,...) for T

Also, GetRecord works by having an index, but I don't really care about it that much, as long as I can iterate over the records and get the right type.

Comment: Your sample `RIVDataSet` can apperently add many `RIVRecord<float>` instances to it's `float_records` vector, but which does `GetFloatRecord` return?  Or should there only be one record of each type?

Comment: no restriction on amount of each type, getRecord would give an index or name or some such (sorry I removed it by accident when stripping)

Comment: Can you edit the question to clarify?  Because I still don't understand which Record `GetRecord` is supposed to return.  Did you mean `getRecord` should have an index parameter?

Comment: Ok, I did, the important thing is, I just want to iterate over the records and get the right type RIVRecord<float>, ... I hope this clarifies it a bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solving this via variadic templates is not very complicated, but requires some additional support types. Let us begin, by looking at the result:

```
template <typename... V>
class many_vectors
{
    static_assert(are_all_different<V...>::value, "All types must be different!");

    std::tuple<std::vector<V>...> _data;

public:
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T>& data()
    { return std::get<index_of<T, V...>::value>(_data); }

    template<typename T>
    std::vector<T> const& data() const
    { return std::get<index_of<T, V...>::value>(_data); }

    template<typename T>
    void push_back(T&& arg)
    { data<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>().push_back(std::forward<T>(arg)); }

    template<typename T, typename... W>
    void emplace_back(W&&... args)
    { data<T>().emplace_back(std::forward<W>(args)...); }
};
```

The `static_assert` defines a very important requirement: Since we are differentiating on types, we must ensure that all types are different. The `_data` member is a [`std::tuple`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/) of the vectors for the different types, and corresponds directly to your `float_records` and `int_records` members.

As an example of providing a member function that refers to one of the vectors by their type the `data` function exposes the individual `vector`s. It uses a helper template to figure out which element of the `tuple` corresponds to your type and gets the result.

The `push_back` function of the vectors is also exposed to show how to use that to provide functions on these. Here [`std::forward`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) is used to implement perfect forwarding on the argument to provide optimal performance. However, using rvalue references in combination with templates parameter deduction can lead to slightly unexpected results. Therefore, any reference on the `T` parameter is removed, so this `push_back` will not work for a `many_vectors` containing reference types. This could be fixed by instead providing two overloads `push_back<T>(T&)` and `push_back<T>(T const&)`.

Finally, the `emplace_back` exposes a function that cannot rely on template parameter argument deduction to figure out which vector it is supposed to utilize. By keeping the `T` template parameter first, we allow a usage scenario in which only `T` is explicitly specified.

Using this, you should be ably to implement arbitrary additional members with similar funcitonality (e.g. `begin<T>` and `end<T>`).

#### Helpers

The most important helper is very simple:

```
template<typename T, typename U, typename... V>
struct index_of : std::integral_constant<size_t, 1 + index_of<T, V...>::value>
{ };

template<typename T, typename... V>
struct index_of<T, T, V...> : std::integral_constant<size_t, 0>
{ };
```

This will fail with a fairly ugly error message, if the first argument is not one of the following at all, so you may wish to improve on that.

The other helper is not much more complicated:

```
template<typename T, typename... V>
struct is_different_than_all : std::integral_constant<bool, true>
{ };

template<typename T, typename U, typename... V>
struct is_different_than_all<T, U, V...>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, !std::is_same<T, U>::value && is_different_than_all<T, V...>::value>
{ };

template<typename... V>
struct are_all_different : std::integral_constant<bool, true>
{ };

template<typename T, typename... V>
struct are_all_different<T, V...>
    : std::integral_constant<bool, is_different_than_all<T, V...>::value && are_all_different<V...>::value>
{ };
```

#### Usage

Yes, usage is as simple as you might hope:

```
v.push_back(int(3));
v.push_back<float>(4);
v.push_back<float>(5);
v.push_back(std::make_pair('a', 'b'));
v.emplace_back<std::pair<char, char>>('c', 'd');

std::cout << "ints:\n";
for(auto i : v.data<int>()) std::cout << i << "\n";

std::cout << "\n" "floats:\n";
for(auto i : v.data<float>()) std::cout << i << "\n";

std::cout << "\n" "char pairs:\n";
for(auto i : v.data<std::pair<char, char>>()) std::cout << i.first << i.second << "\n";
```

With the expected result:

```
ints:
3

floats:
4
5

char pairs:
ab
cd
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it looks very impressive and I think this solves my problem, but if I were to use it in my current design of a dataset containing a vector of records containing the different primitive types I would simply substitute V by RIVRecord<V>? Would your uniqueness enforcement still work? e.g. `std::tuple<std::vector<RIVRecord<V>>...> _data;`

Comment: Ah, you posted this in the time it took me to recreate C++14's `std::get<T>`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0efeb255fe6a19ad

Comment: @Gerard You can(`X<T>` is the same as `X<U>` iff `T` is the same as `U`), but you really do not have to. Instead you can implement the general `many_vectors` template and reuse it to power your special case. This might simplify your code due to separation of concerns.

Comment: @MooingDuck I suppose there should be a free version of `many_vectors::get<T>` for interoperability with `std::get<T>` via ADL

Comment: @gha.st Yes of course, I got it working, thanks a bunch! Very impressive code. On a side note do you have a good reference to learn about advanced template usage such as this?

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks anyway, I appreciate the effort

Comment: @gha.st: kek observes that your signature for `AddRecord` changed, and made the use of implicit conversions impossible.  You should add an overload `template<class T, class U> void emplace_back(U&& arg) {data<T>().push_back(std::forward<U>(arg)); }` which would allow implicit conversions at the expense of having to explicitly specify the destination type.

Comment: @MooingDuck Implicit conversions should still be possible by sacrificing the type deduction (e.g. calling `v.push_back<double>(3)`), but your point on the `emplace_back` as an example is well taken - hopefully my implementation meets your expectations.

Comment: @Gerard Thanks for the praise! Sadly I have no single one reference for learning about advanced c++ features.

Comment: Ok, I have a different issue when using your solution. I tried implementing the template using my RIVDataRecord, but it errors. I think because I am trying to wrap it, what am I doing wrong? By the way, I changed the yPixels to float template, but of course this should actually be also integers, but this also does not seem to compile.

Here is the code I have now: 

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fdfdf3b79e4567e4

Comment: @gha.st: Oh, you're totally right about the conversions: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/76aa476e6dba3577  I hadn't thought that would work

Comment: @Gerard One stupid error by me, and one by you ;). Mine was to not to think about what happens to lvalues, while yours was to not include all necessary headers. Check this out: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/354fa0e7197b6c72

Comment: @Gerard I may have enjoyed this question a bit to much ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a technique called type erasure, you'll have to include another level of indirection however. Some general feedback:

`RIVRecord(std::string _name, std::vector<T> _values)`

Is better as:

`RIVRecord(const std::string& _name, const std::vector<T>& _values)`

In order to avoid unnecessary copies, overall the rule of thumb is to accept arguments as `const&` for most things which aren't a primitive.

`T* Value(int index) { return &values[index]; }`

Is dangerous, if the `size()` goes beyond `capacity()` of your `vector< T >` it will reallocate and invalidate all your pointers. A better interface in my opinion would be to have a `T GetValue< T >()` & `void SetValue< T >( T a_Value )`.

On to type erasure, this is how `RIVDataSet` could look, I'm using a library called Loki here, if you don't want to use Loki I'll give you some pointers afterwards.

```
class RIVDataSet
{
private :
    //How to template this??
    struct HolderBase
    {
        virtual ~HolderBase() {}
    };
    template< typename T >
    struct HolderImpl : HolderBase
    {
        // Use pointer to guarantee validity of returned record
        std::vector< RIVRecord< T >* > m_Record;
    };
    typedef Loki::AssocVector< Loki::TypeInfo, HolderBase* > HolderMap;
    HolderMap m_Records;
public:
    ~RIVDataSet() 
    { 
        for( HolderMap::iterator itrCur = m_Records.begin(); itrCur != m_Records.end(); ++itrCur ) delete itrCur->second; 
    }
    //And this
    template< typename T >
    void AddRecord(const RIVRecord< T >& record ) 
    {
        HolderMap::iterator itrFnd = m_Records.find( typeid( T ) );
        if( itrFnd == m_Records.end() )
            itrFnd = m_Records.insert( std::make_pair( Loki::TypeInfo( typeid( T ) ), new HolderImpl< T >() ) ).first;
        static_cast< HolderImpl< T >* >( itrFnd->second )->m_Record.push_back( new RIVRecord< T >( record ) );
    }
    template< typename T >
    RIVRecord< T >* GetRecord()
    {
        HolderMap::iterator itrFnd = m_Records.find( typeid( T ) );
        assert( itrFnd != m_Records.end() );
        return itrFnd == m_Records.end() ? 0 : static_cast< HolderImpl< T >* >( itrFnd->second )->m_Record.front();
    }
};
```

`Loki::AssocVector` can be substituted for `std::map`, you do however need `Loki::TypeInfo`, which is just a wrapper for `std::type_info`. It's fairly easy to implement one your self if you take a look at the code for it in `Loki`.

Comment: Your advice about taking `const std::string&` is dated.  Instead, he should keep taking the parameters by value, and `std::move` them to the destinations.

Comment: Also, I'm not sure he wants type erasure.  I think he wants each `T` to have it's own vector, which is more correct anyway.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the general feedback. I am not certain if this would work, but I do think gha.st solves it in the most general way. Thanks though

Comment: @MooingDuck: Each T would have its own vector under this scheme, it does require an extra level of indirection & slightly more memory compared to a variadic approach, but has flexibility of not having the type list as a part of the type. Unless I'm misunderstanding, passing by value & moving would first create a copy, and then move that copy, which I fail to see how it would be better than simply passing by const ref & copy construct.

Comment: @Ylisar: Because passing by value & moving would sometimes move and then move, (and one or both may be elided), which is _significantly_ better than simply passing by const ref & copy construct.  Each T would have it's own vector under this scheme, which would require _less_ indirection, and slightly _less_ memory compared to your type-erased approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use variadic templates to create multiple members of the same name but different type. In fact, you can never have two members with the same name. However, you can use multiple inheritance, and put the member in your base classes using variadic base classes. You can then use a member template in your derived class to resolve the ambiguity.

The example below also uses *perfect forwarding* to make sure that if a temporary is passed to `add()`, its resources can be "stolen". You can read more about that [here](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_01.html).

Here is the example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

// This templated base class holds the records for each type.
template <typename T>
class Base {
    public:
        // "T &&v" is a universal reference for perfect forwarding.
        void add(T &&v) { records.push_back(std::forward<T>(v)); }
    private:
        std::vector<T> records;
};

// This inherits from Base<int>, Base<double>, for example, if you instantiate
// DataSet<int, double>.
template <typename... Ts>
class DataSet : public Base<Ts>... {
    public:
        // The purpose of this member template is to resolve ambiguity by specifying
        // which base class's add() function we want to call.  "U &&u" is a
        // universal reference for perfect forwarding.
        template <typename U>
        void add(U &&u) {
            Base<U>::add(std::forward<U>(u));
        }
};

int main() {
    DataSet<int, double> ds;
    ds.add(1);
    ds.add(3.14);
}
```

Comment: "You can't use variadic templates to create multiple members of the same name but different type."  However, there is `tuple` which can be used as if you had template members of different types with the same name.

Comment: Your answer is missing `getRecord`, which has a minor trick to it.  Easily doable though.  Also, I would remove the `DataSet::add`, which interferes with implicit conversions.

Comment: @MooingDuck: If `DataSset::add` is removed, then the call to add becomes ambiguous.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Also, which implicit conversion are you referring to?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Never mind about the implicit conversion question, I know now what you meant.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Note that the `tuple` solution by gha.st has the same issue with the implicit conversion, as far as I can tell, due to `data<T>` in `push_back`.

Answer (score 0):

One horrible idea if you really must do it as general is using the "type erasure idiom". It goes something like this (haven't compiled that though but I think it will, and can be further improved by type traits that would link RIVRecordsIndex::Float to the type float and prevent error)

```
class BaseRIVRecord                                                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                            
};                                                                                                                                                           

template <class T>                                                                                                                                           
class RIVRecord : public BaseRIVRecord                                                                                                                       
{                                                                                                                                                            
};                                                                                                                                                           

enum class RIVRecordsIndex                                                                                                                                   
{                                                                                                                                                            
   Float, Int                                                                                                                                                   
};                                                                                                                                                           

class RIVDataSet                                                                                                                                             
{                                                                                                                                                            
public:                                                                                                                                                         
    template<RIVRecordsIndex I, typename T>                                                                                                                                         
    void addRecord()                                                                                                                                
    {                                                                                                                                                            
         allmightyRecords.resize(I+1);                                                                                                                            
         allmightyRecords[I].push_back(new RIVRecord<T>());                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                            

    template<RIVRecordsIndex I, typename T>                                                                                                                                         
    RIVRecord<T>* get(unsigned int index)                                                                               
    {                                                                                                                                                            
         return static_cast<RIVRecord<T>*>(allmighyRecords[I][index]);                                                                               
    }
private:                                                                                                                                                            
    std::vector<std::vector<BaseRIVRecord*>> allmightyRecords;                                                                                                 
};                                                                                                                                                           

int main()
{
     RIVDataSet set;
     set.addRecord<RIVRecordsIndex::Float, float>();
     set.addRecord<RIVRecordsIndex::Float, float>();
     set.addRecord<RIVRecordsIndex::Int, int>();

     RIVRecord<int> r = set.get<RIVRecordsIndex::Int, int>(0);
}
```

If you decide to do this stuff make sure you do not slice the inherited type (i.e. use vector of pointers). Do use some kind of type traits to prevent error calls like set.get. Again I have no time to actually compile that, it is just an idea thrown to further develop.